# qemu-img createで作成したイメージをvirt-installで指定するとエラーが発生する

Tags: qemu

質問させて頂きます。

起きている現象はタイトルの通り、qemu-img createで作成したイメージをvirt-installで指定するとエラーが発生する状態です。

具体的には、以下のコマンドを実行後

```
qemu-img create  overcloud-ctrl.qcow2 41G
```

以下のコマンドを実行するとエラーが発生します

```
/usr/bin/virt-install \
   --name overcloud-ctrl \
   --ram 6144 --vcpus 2 \
   --os-variant centos7.0 \
   ./overcloud-ctrl.qcow2 \
   --noautoconsole \
   --vnc \
   --network network:data1 --mac=52:54:00:c0:87:36 \
   --network network:internals \
   --cpu SandyBridge,+vmx \
   --graphics vnc,listen=0.0.0.0 \
   --dry-run --print-xml > overcloud-ctrl.xml
```

エラー内容は

```
virt-install: error: unrecognized arguments: ./overcloud-ctrl.qcow2
```

となります。

./overcloud-ctrl.qcow2　は存在し、Qemu-img infoで確かめても存在します。

```
qemu-img info  overcloud-ctrl.qcow2
image: overcloud-ctrl.qcow2
file format: raw
virtual size: 41G (44023414784 bytes)
disk size: 0
```

以下の記事を確認しながらKVMでVMを作成途中でした。
https://qiita.com/s1061123/items/c7f3e47d66e8cbea1a7c

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

`unrecognized arguments` なので、コマンドライン引数が認識できないのであって、
ファイルの中身がおかしいという意味ではありません。

ざっと検索してみたところ、

```
./overcloud-ctrl.qcow2 \
```

これは

```
--disk ./overcloud-ctrl.qcow2 \
```

なのでは?

---

コメントの追加質問について。

https://www.redhat.com/archives/virt-tools-list/2013-May/msg00093.html

↑このページを見ると、

- 他のオプションを外してみてはどうか
- 特に `--noautoconsole` を外してみてはどうか

といったところでしょうか。

なお、私は virt-install については全く知りません。
一つ目の回答は私の常識範囲内で回答できましたが、virt-install 専用のメッセージだと私には対処が難しいです。もしこれでうまくいかなかった場合(または更なる問題が見つかった場合)は、他の方の回答を待つか、問題になっている部分を切り出して新たに質問を立てるのが良いと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
該当箇所については、エラーは発生しなくなりました。
しかし、次の箇所でエラーが発生している状態です。。。
ERROR    Cannot mix --graphics and old style graphical options

ググってもそれらしき対処法が出ず困っております…

Comment: @kakokakoko 回答に追記しました。

Comment: @kakokakoko [エラーの発生箇所](https://github.com/virt-manager/virt-manager/blob/master/virt-install#L271)を見る限り、`--vnc` オプションを外すと良さそうです。

Answer (score 1):

ご連絡遅れ、大変申し訳ございませんでした。
ありがとうございます。先程、無事解決致しました。`--vnc`, `--noautoconsole`オプションを外すことで動作致しました。